# Android ViewPager: How to scrolling event beyond the end of the pager

Tags: android

I have a `ViewPager` which displays a bunch of pages, what I'd like to do is to detect when the user is at the last page and still attempting to scroll to the next page (of course this will not work). At that time the app should begin loading new pages and display them after loaded.

Is there any built in event that handles this event? Or how can I do it manually?

Comment: If the user in last page and try to scroll then restart from position 1 again, If you don't have data how will you display

Comment: sounds like horizontal pull-to-refresh listview, Do you want to add items to the pager dynamically? then have to manage fetching them also